# How to transfer Image files over WCF?

Tags: image, wcf, transfer

I am trying to transfer a Image file from my data base to a self care portal. But every time I try to retrieve a file over size 80KB, the retrieved file gets corrupted and I am unable to open that file. The maximum size of file that I may try to retrieve is upto 3MB
I am using stream mode file transfer. Has anyone ever faced and resolved this issue, please help here

Answer (score 5):

Please refer these links

1. [Transferring files with WCF](http://garfoot.com/blog/2008/06/transferring-large-files-using-wcf/)
2. [Streaming with WCF](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/endpoint/archive/2010/11/24/streaming-over-http-with-wcf.aspx)